# neo4j cypher update existing node or create new node

Tags: merge, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with approximately nine million nodes, and twelve million relationships. For each of the nodes within the graph there is a subset of properties for each respective node which forms a unique identity for the node, by Label. The graph is being updated by various data sources which augment existing nodes within the graph, or create new nodes if the nodes don't exist. I don't want to create duplicates according to the unique set of properties within the graph during the update.

For example, I have People in the graph, and their uniqueness is determined by their first name and last name. The following code is to create two *distinct* people:

```
CREATE (p:Person{first:"barry",last:"smith",height:187});
CREATE (p:Person{first:"fred",last:"jones",language:"welsh"});
```

Later, from one of the data sources I receive the following data records (one per line):

```
first: "fred", last: "lake", height: 201
first: "barry", last: "smith", language: "english"
first: "fred", last: "jones", language: "welsh", height: 188
first: "fred", last: "jones", eyes: "brown"
first: "barry", last: "smith"
```

After updating the graph I want to have the following nodes:

```
(:Person{first:"fred",last:"jones",language:"welsh",height:"188,eyes:"brown"})
(:Person{first:"barry",last:"smith",language"english",height:187})
(:Person{first:"fred",last"lake",height:201})
```

I'm trying to formulate a `MERGE` query which can do this kind of update. I have come up with the following approach:

- Start with a `MERGE` that uses the uniqueness properties (`first` and `last` from the example) to find or create the initial node;
- Then do a `SET` containing each property defined in the incoming record.

So, for the three examples records given above:

```
MERGE (p:Person{first:"fred",last:"lake"}) SET p.height = 201;
MERGE (p:Person{first:"barry",last:"smith"}) SET p.language = "english";
MERGE (p:Person{first:"fred",last:"jones"}) SET p.language = "welsh", p.height = 188;
MERGE (p:Person{first:"fred",last:"jones"}) SET p.eyes = "brown";
MERGE (p:Person{first:"barry",last:"smith"});
```

I've tried this out and it works, but I'm curious to know whether this is the best way (most efficient...) to ensure uniqueness in the nodes based on a set of properties, and allow additional information to be added (or not) as updates come in over time?

Comment: Do you have a list of properties or can they be anything?

Comment: @MarcoCI Thanks for your reply. It's highly likely that the set of properties is known, but may change over time. How would this knowledge affect the implementation (knowing the set or not knowing the set), do you think?

Comment: a "Fred Jones" should never speak Welsh. He should be named Llwyr Culhwch or something like that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just a naive approach: what if you run a `MERGE` and just create or update it?

Given your list of records, consider each record as a map:

```
{ first: "fred", last: "lake", height: 201 }
{ first: "barry", last: "smith", language: "english" }
{ first: "fred", last: "jones", language: "welsh", height: 188 }
{ first: "fred", last: "jones", eyes: "brown" }
{ first: "barry", last: "smith" }
```

Then write your query in a parametric way:

```
MERGE (p:Person { first: { map }.first, last: { map }.last })
ON CREATE SET p = { map }
ON MATCH  SET p += { map }
```

Description of the query:

- In case of creation it should create a new node using all the properties passed in the `{map}`
- In case of matching [it should add new properties to the node without deleting any](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-set.html#set-adding-properties-from-maps)

I've run some queries in console of [the page linked above](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-set.html#set-adding-properties-from-maps) with a `MERGE ON MATCH` and it seems to update existing properties to new values.
The queries I've run are the following:

```
MATCH (peter { name: 'Peter' }) RETURN peter
MERGE (peter { name: 'Peter' }) ON MATCH SET peter += { hungry: TRUE , position: 'Entrepreneur' }
MATCH (peter { name: 'Peter' }) RETURN peter
// added two new properties here
MERGE (peter { name: 'Peter' }) ON MATCH SET peter += { hungry: FALSE , position: 'Entrepreneur' }
MATCH (peter { name: 'Peter' }) RETURN peter
// hungry is now false in here
```

Comment: Thanks for your follow up advice: much appreciated. After my initial post I read more about the `MERGE` with *map* functionality, and I think this looks like a good solution.

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket on the match :)

Comment: This was good, thanks! But I think the n in 'n =' and 'n +='  should be a p?

Comment: Yes indeed @L.Heinrichs I've edited the answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that this is the best way. Depending on the Neo4j interface you are using, you could write a single query that would handle everything without custom SET commands, but I'm guessing that you were just simplifying the question and have that covered.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The implementation will be server based. So traffic on the wire will be important. Cypher appears to facilitate detailed actions in a single call. Should I be looking more closely at the other RESTful APIs? (For performance, that is.)

Comment: Have you looked at the REST-based Cypher interface? If you haven't, it allows you to make use of parameters in queries, which is quite powerful. I don't think that merging is available otherwise.